Proving mutual independence of $(X, Y, Z)$ implies independence of $X$ and $Y$ given $Z$
I want to prove or disprove the following result:
let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $X, Y, Z : \Omega \to \mathbb R$ be mutually independent, $(\mathcal F, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$-measurable random variables; then $X$ and $Y$ are independent given $Z$.
I read the answer to the following question: Does mutual independence of X, Y, Z implies conditional independence of X and Y, given Z however it seems to me that it assumes $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ have a density (with respect to the same measure). This is not an assumption I wish to make.
The characterisation of conditional independence, probability and independence I would like to use is as follows (please tell if they are not correct):

$X$ and $Y$ are independent given $Z$ if $\mathbb P((X, Y) \in A \times B | Z) = \mathbb P(X \in A | Z) \mathbb P(Y \in B | Z)$ holds for every pair of borelian sets $(A, B)$;
$\mathbb P(Y \in A | Z) = \mathbb E[\boldsymbol 1_{A} \circ Y | Z]$ for every borelian set $A$;
$\mathbb E[U | Z]$ for an $(\mathcal F, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$-measurable variable is defined as the only (up to almost-everywhere equality) $(\sigma(Z), \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$-measurable random variable that satisfies $\int_\Omega \boldsymbol (1_A \circ U)\ U \text d\mathbb P = \int_\Omega \mathbb E[U | Z] \boldsymbol 1_A \circ U \text d \mathbb P$ for every borelian set $A \subseteq \mathbb R$.

I am still quite confused with all this notation and wish to formally derive the result, using measure-theoretic notation instead of probabilistic notation as mush as reasonable.
My questions are:

is the result still correct in the general setting?
is the definition of expected expectation I gave correct (it should be a translation of the definition given in my textbook into measure-theoretic language, but I might have missed something)?
is this characterisation a reasonable starting point to proving the result?
how should I get started?


Not answering your specific questions, but what you are trying to prove is a corollary of the Corollary (the proof of it is also included) contained in this answer.

Where in the referenced thread is anything assumed or asserted about densities? Regardless, you can emulate the argument there: where do you think it breaks down?

@whuber Substituting $p_X$ with the probability measure $\mathbb P_X = \mathbb P \circ X^{-1}$ I would interpret $p_{X, Y | Z}(x,y|z) = p_{X, Y}(x, y)$ as $\mathbb P(X \in A, Y \in B | Z) = \mathbb P(X \in A, Y \in B)$, which I couldn't prove.

As you correctly identified, the goal is to prove for any Borel sets $A$ and $B$, it holds that
\begin{align*}
P(X \in A, Y \in B|Z) = P(X \in A|Z)P(Y \in B|Z), 
\end{align*}
which, by the condition $(X, Y)$ is independent of $Z$, reduces to (check this answer to understand why this reduction holds):
\begin{align*}
P(X \in A, Y \in B) = P(X \in A)P(Y \in B), 
\end{align*}
but this is just a restatement of $X$ and $Y$ are independent. This completes the proof.
